# How to get actorRef without context in its companion object

Tags: scala, akka

If I have following Actor (MyActor) with a companion object.

```
object MyActor {
}
class MyActor extends Actor{
}
```

Now I want to delcare a method in a companion object like following

```
object MyActor{

def doStuff(id:String){
 (myActor ? Message1(id)).map {

}
}
```

where doStuff method will be called by a caller which has no knowledge of actors etc. now doStuff needs "myActor" reference in there. since object MyActor has no actor context or anything what's the way to access "myActor" actor in there?

**EDIT** Initialization of MyActor happens upon application startup, by a totally different Global Object, as follow.

```
val system = ActorSystem("MyActorSystem")
//create all first level actors here
system.actorOf(Props[MyActor], "MyActor")
```

Comment: I don't quite understand what you want, is myActor supposed to be a unique ActorRef? Or whenever you instantiate a new ActorRef, you need that myActor to refer to it?

Comment: @Peter : I edite the question with some more detail as to where MyActor gets initialized etc. let me know if this answers your question?

Answer (score 1):

It sounds like you want to treat the fact that you are using an actor as an implementation detail of whatever service the companion object exposes, but you want to centralize the creation of actors (presumably to give them a supervisor).  One option would be for the companion object to [look up the actor](http://doc.akka.io/docs/akka/snapshot/general/addressing.html).

Another would be to have the creation of the actor hidden in the companion object.  The global object that creates the actors could, rather than creating MyActor directly, call an init method on the companion object with an ActorSystem argument; MyObject could save the ActorRef for later use.  You'd have to make the variable `@volatile` in that case.

Comment: - I am exploring option 1 as option 2 doesn't sound like a clean approach to me. For Option 1 too I need to access "system"(or "context" whatever we call it) from a Global object which creates an actorSystem. so let's say somehow I get access to it in "MyActor" object then do I do context.actorSelection("/user/myActor") ??

Comment: this answer looks reasonable. it also sounds a bit of an anti-pattern to me to have all of these global singletons need to be aware of each other.

Answer (score 1):

If you really want to create your `myActor` elsewhere and then be able to use it in this companion, then you could try something like this:

```
object MyActor {       

   def doStuff(id:String)(implicit sys:ActorSystem) = {
     (sys.actorSelection("/user/MyActor") ? Message1(id)).map {}
   }
}
```

By making the context an input (and it doesn't have to be an implicit, could be explicit too) different pieces of code pass it in/make it available in different ways.  For example, in another actor, you already have the actor system available via `context.system` but if you are outside of an actor, then you will probably have needed to make the actor system itself available on some sort of global object and then imported into scope.

Answer (score 0):

The thing is that, even though it is defined in the companion object of `MyActor`, `doStuff` can't access the reference (`ActorRef`) to the instantiated actor without explicitly importing the `ActorRef` `myActor`.

I think it would be better to write the MyActor object as follows:

```
object MyActor {
   val myActor = system.actorOf(Props[MyActor], "MyActor")

   def doStuff(id:String) = {
     (myActor ? Message1(id)).map {}
   }
}
```

Import this object in your `Global` object so that the creation of `myActor` would be done as soon as the `Global` object is used.

Comment: I think part of the OP's issue is getting an `ActorRefFactory` (an `ActorSystem` or `ActorContext`) in order to spawn/lookup the actor.  In your example, where is `system` coming from?

Comment: From a global object that would be imported where are stored systems, accesses to Redis for example...

Comment: where do I get "system" (or "conetxt" whatever we call it) from in MyActor object? val system = ActorSystem("MyActorSystem") is done in the global object.